# Show that the larger $c$ is the faster ${\rm d}U_t^c=\frac c2h'(U_t^c){\rm d}t+\sqrt c{\rm d}W_t$ converges to its stationary distribution

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process, monte-carlo, stochastic-differential-equations

Given two Markov chains $\left(X^{(1)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $\left(X^{(2)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ with transition kernel $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$, respectively, and a common stationary distribution $\pi$, we say that $\left(X^{(1)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ *converges faster than* $\left(X^{(2)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ if $$\sup_A\left|\kappa_1^n(x,A)-\pi(A)\right|\le\sup_A\left|\kappa_2^n(x,A)-\pi(A)\right|\tag1$$ for all $x$ and $n$.

> How does this notion carry over to continuous-time Markov processes?

To be precise: Assume $(U_t^c)_{t\ge0}$ is a solution of $${\rm d}U_t^c=\frac c2h'(U_t^c){\rm d}t+\sqrt c{\rm d}W_t\tag2$$ with $c>0$, $h\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ such that $h'$ is Lipschitz continuous and a Brownian motion $W$.

Assume $h=\ln f$ for some positive $f\in C^2(\mathbb R)$. It's known that $U^c$ has stationary measure $\mu:=f\lambda^1$ (measure with density $f$ wrt the Lebesgue measure $\lambda^1$; assume $\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda^1=1$).

> I've read that in the sense of the notion above, $U^c$ converges faster than $U^{c'}$ if $c>c'$. How has this to be understood?

Clearly, $(1)$ is the total variation distance of the $n$th power of the transition kernel and the stationary distribution $\pi$. So, I suppose it's meant that we now consider $\sup_A\left|\kappa_t^{(c)}(x,A)-\mu(A)\right|$, where $\left(\kappa^{(c)}_t\right)_{t\ge0}$ is the transition semigroup of $U^{(c)}$. If that's what is meant, how do we see that this quantity (for fixed $x$ and $t$) becomes larges as $c$ becomes larger?

Comment: Here you can directly see that rescaling the time variable and changing the Brownian motion to an equivalent instance will transform the equation from one $c$ to another.

Comment: @LutzL Sure, that's clear to me. How does this answer my question?

Comment: It does not, it is an idea of how to start, thus it is a comment and not an answer. While the Brownian processes do not map directly, the evolution of the distribution follows exactly the time rescalings. As I understand it, you are comparing statistics of the distribution?

Comment: @LutzL Each side of $(1)$ is measuring the total variation distance of the $n$th step transition probability measure $\kappa_i^n(x,\;\cdot\;)$ (corresponding to the chain started in $x$) and the stationary measure $\pi$. $(1)$ expresses that $\left(X^{(1)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ is "faster" than $\left(X^{(2)}_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ in stationarity. I want to know how this notion of being "faster" carries over to the continuous time case such that I can compare the processes $U^c$.

Comment: Concerning what you write in the second highlighted paragraph: Where did you read that?

Comment: @MarsPlastic I've read that [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=qfRsAIKZ4rIC&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=%22It+follows+that+this+diffusion+is+optimized%22&source=bl&ots=Rcx4aQ3a7X&sig=ACfU3U3OPSpHYyEhe3uTLlYZ811psGTUug&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi5s9Ph2PrgAhUQb1AKHYkKBioQ6AEwA3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22It%20follows%20that%20this%20diffusion%20is%20optimized%22&f=false)

Comment: @MarsPlastic Did you take a look?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your exact question and I am ignoring quite some details, but maybe it helps anyway. The generator of your process can be written as
$$ \mathcal L_c f=\frac{c}{2}(f'' +h'f'), \quad f\in C_c^2(\Bbb R),$$
and with $\mu=e^h\lambda$ you can check that
$$ \mathcal E_c(f):=-\int f \mathcal L_c fd\mu=\frac{c}{2}\int (f')^2d\mu.$$
If $h$ is **concave** and $\int fd\mu=0$, a classical result by Bobkov yields
$$ \int f^2d\mu \le C_1 \int (f')^2d\mu$$
for some $C_1>0$. Together, we have the Poincaré inequality
$$ \|f\|^2_{L^2(\mu)}\le\frac{2C_1}{c}\mathcal E_c(f) ,$$
which implies (by taking derivatives and using Gronwall's Lemma)
$$ \|\kappa^{(c)}_t(\,\cdot\,, f)\|_{L^2(\mu)}\le e^{- C_2 ct} \|f\|_{L^2(\mu)}.$$
This $L^2$-rate for the decay of the semi-group is indeed faster, if one increases $c$.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of the result by Bobkov?

Comment: See here: https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1022874820

Comment: Sorry for responding to this old post, but if your Poincaré inequality has constant $\frac{2C_1}c$, then the factor before $\left\|f\right\|_{L^2(\mu)}$ in the inequality you derived from Gronwall should be $e^{-2\left(\frac{2 C_1}c\right)^{-1}t}=e^{-\frac c{C_1}t}$. And by density of $C_c^2(\mathbb R)$ in $L^2(\mu)$ this inequality should extend to all $f\in L^2(\mu)$ or am I missing something?